# Check was 10 mins elapsed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my function I need to check how much elapsed since last it's execution and it it is greater than 10 min. allow execution. What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

```
clock_t lastExecution ;

boolean isItTime()
{
// ??
}

void doJob()
{
if (isItTime())
  {
  //Do what I need
  lastExecution = clock();
  }
}
```

Comment: `return clock() > lastExecution + 10mins`?

Comment: how to add 10mins to lastExecution?

Comment: Depends on what `clock()` returns. If it returns the time in seconds than it is `10 * 60`. For milliseconds it is `10 * 60 * 1000`. I don't know what `clock` you have so I can't look it up.

Comment: There is CLOCKS_PER_SEC macro.

Comment: `boolean`? Did you `typedef` for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MSVC++ [clock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx) returns the elapsed time (wall clock, not CPU time consumed), so the solution with `clock()` can use `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro.

```
boolean isItTime()
{
    return (clock()-lastExecution) >= 10*60*CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

However, [CppReference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) that `std::clock` must return the CPU time consumed, not wall clock time passed. [So it seems to do on Linux](http://kera.name/articles/2011/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-11-sleep-your-way-to-success/), therefore the solution for Linux should be different if you want to check for wall clock time rather than CPU time.

So a cross-platform C++ solution could use [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) :

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> lastExecution 
    = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

bool isItTime()
{
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsedSeconds =
        std::chrono::system_clock::now() - lastExecution;
    return elapsedSeconds.count() >= /* 10 minutes */ 10 * 60;
}

void doJob()
{
if (isItTime())
  {
  //Do what I need
  lastExecution = std::chrono::system_clock::now()
  }
}
```

There are still nuances to be aware of, e.g. you may prefer [std::chrono::steady_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/) in case you want physical 10 minutes elapsed, so that `isItTime()` does not return `true` in case the user advances the clock 10 minutes ahead, or the system starts daylight saving time, or the system just updates its time ahead when synchronizing with internet time.

Comment: The solution with `clock()` is broken. http://kera.name/articles/2011/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-11-sleep-your-way-to-success/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for pointing that out, I've been using MSVC++ so much that I forgot that `clock()` should compute CPU time according to the standard. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow I didn't know MSVC++ did that. How lame :(

Answer (score 4):

Using modern C++, it becomes a lot easier to read imho:

```
#include <chrono>

void f() {
    using namespace ::std::chrono;
    static auto last_run = steady_clock::now();

    if(steady_clock::now() - last_run >= 10min) {
        // well, this was easy!
    }
    last_run = steady_clock::now();
}
```

Note that it is not thread safe and "probably" will not enter the `>= 10min` condition on the initial run.

Additionally, `steady_clock` is used to ensure that funny effects like the begin or end of Daylight Saving Time do not wreak havoc on your notion of a duration (e.g. the duration between 1 second before the start of DST and 1 second afterwards should be 2 seconds, not 1 hour and 2 seconds)

[example](https://ideone.com/cDK55h)